# Magento2 Rest API reset password with different store id getting default email template

Tags: magento2, email-templates, rest-api, webapi

I am using Rest API to reset password of customer, i have already passed websiteId for different store but when i am getting reset password email, it is coming of default store not the store i have passed, can anyone let me know what should i do? Please find below screenshots for your reference:

[image: postman api]
[image: email]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use different endpoint, please read this answer, it will show you how we can use the correct endpoint URL, but in general you have to put the store view code before /V!

**{store code}**/V1/...

[How to add a product to a specific website in Magento 2 codebase via api](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/240923/how-to-add-a-product-to-a-specific-website-in-magento-2-codebase-via-api/241402#241402)

Comment: I have used your instruction and tried to do it but i am getting following error in response api:

Error:
{
    "message": "Invalid value of \"%value\" provided for the %fieldName field.",
    "parameters": {
        "fieldName": "regionId",
        "value": "3"
    }
}

API URL:http://127.0.0.1/bannerbuzzmagento2/rest/ca/V1/customers/password
NOTE: ca is my storeview code.

Comment: can you post here the json ?

Comment: Here it is:
{
    "message": "Invalid value of \"%value\" provided for the %fieldName field.",
    "parameters": {
        "fieldName": "regionId",
        "value": "3"
    }
}

Comment: not the response json but the requested json , no need for the real email just the structure

Comment: Here is request json:
{
 "email": "bhargav@commercepundit.com",
 "template": "email_reminder",
 "websiteId": 2
}